# JavaScript accordion behavior when it won't expand - set an href?

Tags: javascript, html, accordion

I have a JavaScript accordion on this [site](http://library.francis.edu) that features within it, the primary functionality for the site. It is based off of this [post](http://www.richnetapps.com/javascript-animated-collapsible-panels-without-frameworks/).

When someone has JavaScript disabled or for whatever reason the panels aren't expanding, is there a way to set it so that clicking on them will act as a traditional hyperlink?

That way users can still be directed to content that they need and the site isn't "broken" for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [noscript](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/noscript.html) tag to provide content for those that have JS disabled. That should work no matter what plugin you're using.

Read more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/noscript

So, basically, you can really go creative and build a separate menu for non-JS users.